# Shell script (bourne and/or bash) RegEx over Multiple Lines

Tags: regex, bash, shell, multiline

How do I achieve the following in Shell Script (**bourne and/or bash**)... something similar to what I can, using RegEx on a file (content sample below)

1. I need to match the pattern, and then -
2. Capture the content to the right side of 'LD_PRELOAD=' into a variable.

File Content:

```
blah
blah blah
#Some comment
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6

export LD_PRELOAD

#more comments
```

The following RegEx works fine on the online Regex Builder (https://regex101.com/r/XW0JVR/1)

```
/LD_PRELOAD=(\S+)[\n\r]+^\s*export\s+LD_PRELOAD/gm
```

---

I tried the following using Shell Script, but it doesn't work...

```
#!/bin/bash
envvars_stdFile="tempEnvVarsStd"

regEx="LD_PRELOAD=(\S+)[\n\r]+^\s*export\s+LD_PRELOAD"

if [[ "${envvars_stdFile}" =~ "${regEx}" ]]
then
    cppLib="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    echo "cppLib is: $cppLib"
else
   echo "RegEx Pattern (${regEx}) doesn't match in file: $envvars_stdFile"
fi
```

It Produces:
**RegEx Pattern (LD_PRELOAD=(\S+)[\n\r]+^\s*export\s+LD_PRELOAD) doesn't match in file: tempEnvVarsStd**

Comment: What you're asking for is unclear, what is your end goal with this script? Have you written any code to show as an example?

Comment: My question is basically about Multi Line search in a file using Shell Scripting  (bourne or bash).  As indicated in the OP, I need to first match the lines and then capture the group of interest into a variable.

Comment: There are several things to consider and several ways to go on about it but I doubt that bash will be your best option. As far as the regex, is that necessary? If all you need is to match "LD_PRELOAD" you can first just match that.. (Using awk, grep, or any other tool for that matter) Then simplify your expression to match whatever is after the "=".

Comment: I need to match "LD_PRELOAD=" and "export LD_PRELOAD" lines. That's why I thought RegEx is straight-forward...

Comment: By the way, following shell script code snippet doesn't work for me...

#!/bin/bash
envvars_stdFile="tempEnvVarsStd"

regEx="LD_PRELOAD=(\S+)[\n\r]+^\s*export\s+LD_PRELOAD"

if [[ "${envvars_stdFile}" =~ "${regEx}" ]]
then
 cppLib="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
 echo "cppLib is: $cppLib"
else
   echo "RegEx Pattern (${regEx}) doesn't match in file: $envvars_stdFile"
fi

it produces:
"RegEx Pattern (LD_PRELOAD=(\S+)[\n\r]+^\s*export\s+LD_PRELOAD) doesn't match in file: tempEnvVarsStd"

Comment: Please append that to your question so everyone can see it

Comment: With GNU grep: `variable=$(grep -Po '^LD_PRELOAD=\K.*' file)`

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks, but I need to make sure the following line 'export LD_PRELOAD' also exists with my check... Is there a way to combine both ?

Comment: Try this with GNU grep: `variable=$(grep -Poz '^LD_PRELOAD=\K.*(?=(\n.*)*^export LD_PRELOAD$)' file)`

Comment: Tip: You can make life easier on yourself by starting small. If you try the regex `LD_PRELOAD` or even `.*` in your code, you'll find that it doesn't match either.

Comment: @cyrus Thanks.  your latest update gets the job done... Can you help explain your RegEx ?

Also, how do I mark your response as a working answer/solution?
Sorry I'm newbie to SO.

Comment: As first step: `grep -Poz 'LD_PRELOAD=.*(\n.*)*export LD_PRELOAD' file`. This grabs your line with `LD_PRELOAD=`, line with `export LD_PRELOAD` and all lines between those lines. Next step: `\K` removes matching part before `\K` and `(?=regex)` removes part that matches this regex. It remains only part after `=` in first line. See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858) and `man grep` for options `-P` `-o` and `-z`.

Comment: @cyrus That helps!  

Now, I would really like your solution more visible...  can you paste your solution as "an answer" to my question?  so I can rank it as "working" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Cyrus.  I ended up using his suggestion.  Posting his suggestion here for more visibility, for others looking for similar question of Shell Script MultiLine RegEx...

```
variable=$(grep -Poz '^LD_PRELOAD=\K.*(?=(\n.*)*^export LD_PRELOAD$)' file)
```